# wrong url redirect when setting github pages custom domain

Tags: github, github-pages

i follow this link :https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages to set up my custom domain(my domain is vikingmute.com)

1.set up CNAME file, here:https://github.com/vikingmute/vikingmute.github.com/blob/master/CNAME

2.change the domain A record: i have already change it, you can dig vikingmute.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd to check it out

but now my domain redirect to http://vikingmute.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Can anybody tell me where is the problem?

Thx a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working now. Sounds like it was a DNS Caching issue.